# My phone was stolen: Is there any way I can recover a backup of Whatsapp from the desktop application which is still linked to the phone?

Tags: mac, backup, whatsapp.app

My Android phone was stolen a few days ago. Since then, it is always been offline / switched off. On my Mac, however, I can still use the Whatsapp desktop app which I had linked to my phone.

I plan to buy a SIM with the same number and re-install Whatsapp, but I have no backup to restore as I had disabled the backup feature on the phone.

Is there any way to make a backup from the desktop app? More generally, is there any way I can recover my account conversations/data/images ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the desktop version pulls data from the cloud but if you turned off backup on mobile, there's no way to do what you want other than to manually screenshot it, save files that are available, etc.

Do you have a backup of your phone that you could restore to a new phone? That may do it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, no backup.